How to use WIMCreateFile winapi?
I'm unable to get the WIMCreateFile API working:
#include <windows.h>
#include <wimgapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wimgapi.lib")

class CCoInitialize
{
public:
    CCoInitialize(DWORD dwCoInit = COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) : m_hr(CoInitializeEx(NULL, dwCoInit)) {}
    ~CCoInitialize() { if (SUCCEEDED(m_hr)) CoUninitialize(); }
    operator HRESULT() const { return m_hr; }
    HRESULT m_hr;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CCoInitialize init(COINIT_MULTITHREADED); // Not sure if it requires com initialization
    if (FAILED(init))
    {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to initialize COM: " << init << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD result = 0;
    HANDLE handle = WIMCreateFile(
        L"E:\\sources\\install.esd",      // Path
        WIM_GENERIC_READ,               // Access
        WIM_OPEN_EXISTING,              // Creation Disposition
        0,                              // Flags
        0,                              // Compression Type
        &result                         // Creation Result
    );
    DWORD err = GetLastError();

    // ... WIMApplyImage
    // ...
    return 0;
}


I'm getting a null handle, result 0, and last error:

ERROR_BAD_FORMAT
11 (0xB)
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Instead of a Windows installation file of type .esd i have also tried with a .wim file and i have got the same error.
Testing the command with the same .esd file directly from cmd it does work correctly:
dism /apply-image /imagefile:E:\sources\install.esd /index:6 /applydir:F:\
What BAD_FORMAT is this?

not familiar with the API, but i see a c/c++ issue: if you want to use a backslash literally in a c/c++ string, you need to double (escape) it: L"E:\\sources\\install.esd" (or else using forward slashes, which works fine on Windows)

@jdigital sorry it was a typo when creating a reproducible example, i have edited the question to fix it.

@jdigital or use a raw string literal, which doesn't need escaping.

Might want to try Flags = 0x20000000, from here https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/src/vhd.c#L597

@SimonMourier using this flag it succeeded, thank you, do you know if its safe to use multithreading on the dism apis that perform any kind of modification on the Windows image? i created a new question about this.
